# pandas - regex to extract text, return whole text if pattern not found

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

### EDIT: Updated one more part to question

I have a pandas dataframe "data" like below:

```
col1
-----
sample data1(xyz)
sample data2(xyz123)
sample data3
sample data4
```

I want to create a new column based on the above column, which contains text before the opening paranthesis "(".
However, if the row does not contain the bracket, it should get the orginal text.

I have below code based on the str.extract function:

```
data["NewCol"] =data["col1"].str.extract("(.*?)\(")
```

Current result (It puts NaN, if the pattern is not found.):

```
NewCol
-----
sample data1
sample data2
NaN
NaN
```

Expected result(should put original text, if pattern is not found):

```
NewCol
-----
sample data1
sample data2
sample data3
sample data4
```

How can I get the expected result? There must be a way to do it just in one command, its python! Need some help here folks!

Note: Its not really required to use the the extract funtion. If some other function does the trick, its fine for me.

### EDIT:
PART 2

For the same dataset, What if I want to perform similar kind of action for the text between the brackets?

My code:

```
data["NewCol"] =data["col1"].str.extract("\((.*?)\)")
```

Current result (It puts NaN, if the pattern is not found.):

```
NewCol
-----
xyz
xyz123
NaN
NaN
```

Expected result(should put original text, if pattern is not found):

```
NewCol
-----
xyz
xyz123
sample data3
sample data4
```

What can the regex be for solving this?

Comment: With the updates it has become increasingly unclear what you are trying to ask. Please try and use one question per post, and ask a new one if you have to make substantial edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can `replace` the trailing part with empty string:

```
df['col1'].str.replace('\(.+$', '')
```

Output:

```
0    sample data1
1    sample data2
2    sample data3
3    sample data4
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Or extract the non-`(` characters at the beginning:

```
df['col1'].str.extract("^([^\(]+)")
```

Output:

```
              0
0  sample data1
1  sample data2
2  sample data3
3  sample data4
```

Comment: This solution is bang on, I have added one more part to the question for similar kind of scenrio, but for text between paranthesis. Can you help me out there as well please ?

Comment: Simplest is chain what you already have with `fillna(df['col1']‘

Comment: I understand, this makes sense. You mean something like: df["NewCol"] =df["col1"].str.extract("\\((.*?)\\)").fillna(df["col1"])? This does not seem to be working. for NaN, it fills with the text on row 0 from 'col1' into both NaN. Strange? the new value for both NaN is - sample data1(xyz)

Answer (score 1):

With your provided sample data, you don't need a regex, instead you can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [1764]: df.col1.str.split('(').str[0]
Out[1764]: 
0    sample data1
1    sample data2
2    sample data3
3    sample data4
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: This solution also works fine. Would we be able to solve part 2 (edited question) with split function ?